# what is the difference between $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ and $\mathbb{F}(t^p)$ where $p$ is prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

what is the difference  between  $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ and  $\mathbb{F}(t^p)$ where $p$ is prime?

I know that $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ denote the field of polynomial where  coefficients is belong to $\mathbb{F_p}$

Here Im confused about $\mathbb{F}(t^p)$

what is the meaning of $\mathbb{F}(t^p)?$

Comment: $\mathbb F(t^p)$ would be the polynomials in $t^p$ with coefficients in $\mathbb F$, whatever $\mathbb F$ happens to be.

Comment: Adding to @RobertIsrael's comment: the parentheses here indicates that the set consist of **fractions** of polynomials, not only polynomials (which is indicated with square brackets). For example, $$\frac{1-t^p+(t^p)^5}{1+t^p-(t^p)^2} \in \mathbb F(t^p).$$

Comment: @azif00 i think denominator should be $1$  ,i mean $1 -t^p + (t^p)^5$

Comment: @jasmine What?! That is just an example, but of couse any polynomial in $\mathbb F[t^p]$ has denominator equal to $1$, and so $\mathbb F[t^p] \subset \mathbb F(t^p)$.

Comment: Recall the general def' of $K(a)$ for a field extension $L/K$ and $a \in L$.